# How to I force single consumer on annotation drive rabbitmq spring application

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm scratching my head with something here. I need to enable an app to have a single consumer for a queue. So my first gut reaction was to do this:

```
    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonConverter());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(1);
        return factory;
    }
```

As I sent some messages to the queue for testing, I did notice that only one listener was active at a time, but I noticed this in the logs too:

```
2024-02-29T16:50:54.338-05:00 DEBUG 49772 --- [pool-2-thread-9] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Storing delivery for consumerTag: 'amq.ctag-EM8Q3ba8sEeww7wnKOwY3Q' with deliveryTag: '38' in Consumer@25de8898: tags=[[amq.ctag-EM8Q3ba8sEeww7wnKOwY3Q]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@172.16.17.220:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@ad0bb4e Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@19705650 [delegate=amqp://guest@172.16.17.220:5672/, localPort=65348], acknowledgeMode=MANUAL local queue size=30
2024-02-29T16:50:54.466-05:00 DEBUG 49772 --- [ool-2-thread-10] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Storing delivery for consumerTag: 'amq.ctag-EM8Q3ba8sEeww7wnKOwY3Q' with deliveryTag: '39' in Consumer@25de8898: tags=[[amq.ctag-EM8Q3ba8sEeww7wnKOwY3Q]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@172.16.17.220:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@ad0bb4e Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@19705650 [delegate=amqp://guest@172.16.17.220:5672/, localPort=65348], acknowledgeMode=MANUAL local queue size=31
```

And while looking at the Rabbit console I also noticed that messages were in unack state, but not ready.

So I guess the `BlockingQueueConsumer` does remove them from the queue, and controls concurrency internally. Is there a way to actually force just one message being pulled at a time using Annotations? Or do I have to switch to a manual poll to achieve that?

Thanks folks

Comment: Hello my friend! Long time no see! Let me answer you something. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Artem, indeed long time no see my friend, thank you so much for the help, my spring-fu has been a bit rusty over the past few years :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that purpose you must not use `factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(1);`.
Leave it as-is. There is the logic in the `AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop()`:

```
boolean receivedOk = receiveAndExecute(this.consumer); // At least one message received
if (SimpleMessageListenerContainer.this.maxConcurrentConsumers != null) {
    checkAdjust(receivedOk);
}
```

So, we really do try to start a new `BlockingQueueConsumer` if that property is not `null`.

You can find much more info in JavaDocs of the `concurrency` props in the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`.

There is also this one which might be some kind of interest for your use-case:

```
/**
 * Set to true for an exclusive consumer - if true, the concurrency must be 1.
 * @param exclusive true for an exclusive consumer.
 */
@Override
public final void setExclusive(boolean exclusive) {
```

There is also some info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/listener-concurrency.html

You might also be interested in this option to be set to `1`:

```
/**
 * Tell the broker how many messages to send to each consumer in a single request.
 * Often this can be set quite high to improve throughput.
 * @param prefetchCount the prefetch count
 * @see com.rabbitmq.client.Channel#basicQos(int, boolean)
 */
public void setPrefetchCount(int prefetchCount) {
```